# Uncluttering the axis labels of a ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I have a small `data` where 8 people have picked one of five answer choices for 4 questions. But these five answer choices for each question is different.

Currently, if I `facet_wrap()` over the questions, the flipped `x` axis in each row shows 10 answer choices as the axis labels (see pic. below).

These labels look very messy. Is there a compact way (e.g., maybe not using `facet_wrap`) of visualizing this data where flipped `x` axis labels look not so messy (showing only the 5 answer choices for each question as labels for that question (i.e., 5 unique axis labels for `Representation`, 5 unique axis labels for `Solidification` etc.))?

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/surv.csv')

names(data)[2:5] <- c("Representation", "Solidification", "Application", "Confidence")

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
  mutate(name = name, 
         value = str_wrap(value, 50)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(value, fill = name), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(.~name) + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8))
```

[image]

Comment: It is better for future readers if you include the data directly into the question. Please consider my edit that fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `facet_wrap(..., scales = "free_y")`:

(I also changed the string wrapping length to 30)

```
data %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
    mutate(name = name, 
           value = str_wrap(value, 30)) %>%
    ggplot() + 
    geom_bar(aes(value, fill = name), show.legend = FALSE) + 
    facet_wrap(.~name, scales = "free_y") + 
    coord_flip() +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8))
```

[image: plot]

**EDIT** previous wrong answer:

> You need to clean up your `value` column to be orthogonal to the
> `name` column. Translate the answers into the same values for every
> question, e.g.
>
> strongly agree -- agree -- neutral -- disagree -- strongly disagree
>
> The you have shorter values on the y axis that are also the same for
> each facet.
>
> Your data set could look like this:
>
> ```
> Representation "strongly agree"  "The assignment highly reflected the
> class\ninstructions"             4240222 Solidification "strongly
> agree"  "The assignment highly helped me solidify the key\nconcepts"  
> 4240222 Application    "strongly agree"  "The assignment gave me a
> great opportunity to\napply what I learned" 4240222 Confidence    
> "strongly agree"  "Strongly Agree"                                    
> 4187679 Representation agree             "The assignment reflected the
> class instructions"                     4187679 Solidification agree  
> "The assignment helped me solidify the key concepts"                 
> 4187679 Application    "strongly agree"  "The assignment gave me a
> great opportunity to\napply what I learned" 4187679 Confidence    
> neutral           "Neutral"                                           
> 4110077 Representation "strongly agree"  "The assignment highly
> reflected the class\ninstructions"             4110077 Solidification
> agree             "The assignment helped me solidify the key concepts"
> ```
>
> you can set up a translation table like this:
>
> ````
> The assignment highly reflected the class instructions      strongly
> agree;  The assignment highly helped me solidify the key concepts 
> strongly agree;  The assignment gave me a great opportunity to apply
> what I learned strongly agree;  Strongly Agree agree;           The
> assignment reflected the class instructions agree;           The
> assignment helped me solidify the key concepts agree;           Agree
> neutral;         Neutral                                              
> ....' ) ```
>
> Then you can use
> [`left_join()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) to
> add the correct values of `translate$grade` to your data based on the
> common column `value`. "R for data science" has a [longer
> explanation](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html) of joins.
> ````

Comment: You have "completely" misunderstood the OP's question.  OP says "the answer choices for each question are different". But you changed all of the answer choices to be the same i.e., agree, disagree etc.

Comment: akraf, thanks, but it seems you have provided incorrect data. The answer choices for each question are different.

Comment: @Reza ,morouzian oh my bad, thanks. I was in a hurry... I corrected the answer.